# Iframe Scrolling & height not working properly in iPad

Tags: html, ios, ipad, iframe, scroll

after, Lot of struggle and Research at finally, I got the solution to `IFrame` scrolling issue in iPad browsers.

**Solution**:

```
$(function() {
    if (/iPhone|iPod|iPad/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {

        $("iframe").bind("load",function() {
            var b = this.contentWindow.document.body;

            var div = $(document.createElement("div"));
            var divCSS = {
                'height' : $(this.parentNode).height(),
                'width' : $(this.parentNode).width(),
                'overflow' : 'scroll'
            }

            div.css(divCSS);

            // Move the body's children into this wrapper
            while (b.firstChild)
            {
                div.append(b.firstChild);
            }

            // Append the wrapper to the body
            $(b).append(div);
        });
    }
})
```

Its working fine randomly.
Here I am facing two issues are:

1. Iframe Scrolling working randomly means its not working every time I refresh.
2. The same problem "#1", I am having while rotating the device "landscape" to "portrait" & reverse case.